# csvread function supported by MATLAB coder

Tags: matlab, csv, matlab-coder

I have a MATLAB script that contains a `csvread` call to read in data from a csv file. Now I'm trying to compile my MATLAB script into C using MATLAB Coder. However, `csvread` is [not a member of the supported functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html) for C code generation.

The only read from file function I found is `fread` which only reads in binary file. Is there a way to use `fread` to read a csv file or is there any way around this?

Sample MATLAB script:

```
data = csvread('data.csv');
```

Sample csv file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can read in a `.csv` file with `fread`, you'll just need to process it yourself. Let's say you have `myfile.csv`, containing the text `1, 2, 3, 4`.

```
>> fid = fopen('myfile.csv','r');
>> a = fread(fid, 'char')'
a =
    49    44    32    50    44    32    51    44    32    52    13    10
>> b = char(a)
b =
1, 2, 3, 4
>> fclose(fid);
```

All those commands are supported by MATLAB Coder. `b` is now a string containing the text `1, 2, 3, 4`.

You'll now need to process that string to extract the numbers from between the commas. That's the portion of `csvread` that isn't supported by MATLAB Coder, as within `csvread` it uses regular expressions, which aren't supported by MATLAB Coder.

However, you'll probably find it easier than you might think, as the regular expressions within `csvread` have to cover the general case for any `.csv` file (which might include text fields as well as numbers, and fields that are quoted and can have commas within the quotes, and maybe even Unicode text as well). If you just have numbers, commas, and spaces, shouldn't be too hard - just iterate through the text character-by-character, stop each time you find a comma, and call `str2double` on the portion so far.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` is supported by MATLAB Coder and converts the rows into numbers:

```
fid = fopen('data.csv');
data = fscanf(fid, '%d');
fclose(fid);
```

To read the single column in your example.